# jquery DOM distance between two nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have an html page with a lot of nested elements.  I'm trying to find the DOM distance between two nodes, so that I can select visual siblings even though they are not DOM siblings.

```
  <div class='root'>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='family brother'>
        <div class='otherstuff'>Other Stuff</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='family sister'>
        <div class='otherstuff'>More Stuff</div>
        <div class='wrapper>
          <div class='family nephew'>
            <div class='otherstuff'>Yet more stuff</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So, with jQuery:

```
var root = $(".root");
var siblings = root.find(".family");
```

But that will select brother, sister, and nephew.

I can't use

```
var siblings = root.find(".wrapper>.family");
```

because that will also match all three.

And I can't use

```
var siblings = $(".root>.wrapper>.family");
```

because there may be other wrapper elements depending on the template.

What I'm looking for is: given .brother under .root, tell me if another .family is a "sibling" by calculating if the DOM (hierarchical) distance from .brother to .root matches the distance of another .family member from .root.  The resulting set should contain only .brother and .sister, but not .nephew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by JQuery.closest()

It will return the closest matching element from your target element.

Read the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Needed a little more jiggering, but that function unravels it.  Thanks!